# Why do you say "to speaking" in this phrase? The surprising secret to speaking with confidence"

Tags: verbs, usage

Why do you say "to speaking" in this phrase? The surprising secret to speaking with confidence" What is the reason to use ING at the end of the verb speak?

Answer (score 1):

"To" in this construction is a preposition, not part of the infinitive of the verb. In fact the verb "speak" is not a verb at all here, but a gerund.

The construction is **The secret to *noun***, with "to" meaning "of." Thus:

- The secret to math.
- The secret to happiness.
- The secret to speaking with confidence.

Comment: *To* and *of* are not interchangeable here. "The secret to <x>" means a secret that achieves or improves <x>, but <x> itself is not the thing that is secret. "The secret of <y>" could be used either when <y> itself is the secret thing ("The secret of adding cinnamon to hot chocolate") or just that the secret is associated with <y> ("The secret of  the lost mine").

Answer (score 0):

> the surprising secret to speaking with confidence

In this phrase, *speaking* functions as a noun and is called a gerund.

> gerund
> noun [ C ]   LANGUAGE   specialized
> UK  /ˈdʒer.ənd/ US  /ˈdʒer.ənd/

> C1

> a word ending in "-ing" that is made from a verb and used like a noun:
> In the sentence "Everyone enjoyed Tyler's singing", the word "singing" is a gerund.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gerund)

Further reference on the use of the form *to+v+ing* is shown below.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing